# Endogeneity versus multicolinearity in regressions?

Tags: regression, econometrics, multicollinearity, endogeneity

(I limit myself to two explanatory variables to keep it simple)

So as I understand it, when an explanatory variable is highly correlated with another variable then it becomes difficult to distinguish their individual effects. This means that they might explain the model well (for example large R$^2$), but the coefficients get rejected or at least their standard errors are 'quite' large.

Now the advice I got from my study book and a professor was to drop one of the explanatory variables.

But now during another course, a professor told me that leaving out explanatory variables that are correlated is bad. Since it will lead to omitted variable bias and thus endogeneity.
Basically, instead of the explanatory variables being correlated, the leftover explanatory variable will now correlate with the error term. 
And that when you violate cov(x$_i$,u$_i$) = 0, you got a serious problem. 
It difficult to solve, you won't know it is there (since by construction OLS will make the aforementioned covariance zero) and coefficient becomes inconsistent.

So what is worse and what to do?
It seems like whatever I do, it will be bad? Leave it, and you might reject both exp. variables and/or don't get correct estimation for the coefficient.
Remove it, and I will get endogeneity and not be able to get decent results for the left over exp. variable.

On a side note, is endogeneity really a very big problem? According to my previous professor it is the biggest and most serious problem. Atleast the one assumption of the standard OLS assumptions you do not want to have violated.
And how the Hausman test for it, is not so good since you would first need instrumental variables and those are quite difficult to find. So to test it, you would already need the solution.

While my other two econometric professors did not make such a big deal out of it.

Comment: I have never heard of this, do you have any sources?

Comment: About what exactly?

Comment: `leaving out explanatory variables will lead to omitted variable bias and thus endogeneity`.

Comment: Not really, it depends on the correlation between the explanatory variables. So your statement does not hold all the time.

Not to mention, including them can lead to multicollinearity which can be a serious problem.

Comment: That was a direct quote from your question, that was your (professors) statement. I asked for sources about that statement.

Comment: It just one of the causes of endogeneity. The 3 main causes are: omitted variable bias, simultaneity and measurement error. In the case of omitted variable bias, it will turn up when you leave out explanatory variables that are correlated to your other explanatory variable(s). For sources, you would find it in any econometrics textbook. For example: Econometric methods with applications in business and economics by Heij.